# What is this vise or holder?

Tags: hardware-identification

This turned up in cleaning up the shop.

[image: two pics of thingie]

There's a base bar with three attachments. First a round bolt of adjustable angle, the pivot has angle markings "88, 68, 59, 49, CSK". The other two form an axis and have an angled bed as if for something round. One attachment screws down to clamp what's held. The other pushes a base plate along the bed axis. There's also a little plate on the front, able to stick up into the bed's path but without quick adjustment by hand screw.

I'm thinking it's more likely to hold a tool than a workpiece, perhaps knives for turning? What are those funny angle numbers?

**Update**

There's this other item, a disc cutter for short pieces. It shows the same colors though I don't see where the first thing would be mounted, so it might be a red herring.

[image: pushdown disc cutter]

Comment: To me it looks like some kind of pipe bending clamp.  not a clue how it's meant to be used.

Comment: @Graphus, I didn't mean to. It was supposed to help recognition, if related.

Comment: Ah yes, that's a good point! I'll actually delete my previous Comment as it doesn't apply here.

Comment: @Graphus, do you think I should remove that part again as it's not pertinent after all?

Comment: I don't think you need to given your original intent, and as the chosen Answer does address it I think it's best in this case to leave it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The machine is a miter saw, and appears to be unrelated to the first tool: https://www.proxxon.com/en/micromot/27150.php.

The first thing is probably a holding guide for sharpening drill bits (image source: https://dengarden.com/home-improvement/drill-sharpener):

[image: Drill bit holder]

There should be a base where the cylindrical rod goes in.  It allows to position a drill with a fixed angle and rotation next to a bench grinder.

Comment: That makes the angle markings understandable. Might you know what CSK in the 41° or 40° position means?

Comment: @ariola: could be for countersink bits

Comment: Cuts for different materials have different recommended angles, see e.g. [here](https://fdpw.de/wiki/Bohrer). Maybe that's related. But I don't have any better guess, unfortunately.